# Use of the word Refrained

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

'The experience of negative emotions in the flow of life can never be stopped, only refrained!'

Is this sentence grammatically wrong since the preposition 'from' does not follow the word refrained?

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically wrong.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. *Stopped* and *refrained* are synonymous.

Comment: @Matt The transitive sense of _refrain_ is somewhat broader than the current, intransitive sense. It also means ‘restrain, check, hold back’, which is a bit ‘less’ than _stopping_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not aware of this usage. Can you show me an example sentence? "He refrained me" doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Matt It’s archaic and rare nowadays, but the OED does have some citations that match this sense: “I do not know whether they tried the scourging in earnest; I would like to think that the nurses' words refrained them” (1952); “For the first six months..the Party..refrained themselves and kept low” (1895); “If thou wilt refrain the desire of thee and thy company” (Morris’ 1887 translation of the _Odyssey_).

Answer (score 2):

The central issue here is that there exists both a **transitive** verb *refrain* (meaning 'to curb' or 'to restrain') and an **intransitive** verb *refrain*. The transitive form is obsolete or archaic; the intransitive one is still current.

The upshot is that the query sentence is perfectly grammatical, but applies the verb in its archaic sense. *Refrained* is thus not tautologous here; expressed in slightly more modern English, the sentence means

> The experience of negative emotions in the flow of life can never be stopped, only restrained!

Answer (score 0):

The modern usage of the verb *refrain* is intransitive or reflexive.

Transitive verb use:

> I stopped him from killing himself.

Intransitive verb use:

> I stopped, at the junction.

A transitive verb has a target upon which to perpetrate an action.

An intransitive or reflexive verb has oneself as the target of action.

In modern usage, the intransitive usage is normal:

> I refrained from succumbing to the negativity of life.

Due to the intransitive use, we sometimes also use *refrain* reflexively, without much complaint from listeners of the conversation:

> I refrained myself from succumbing to the negativity of life.

However, moving beyond reflexive would be moving into archaic territory

> I refrained my sister from succumbing to the negativity of life.

As the dictionary attests to its archaic transitive usage:

> [re·frain](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/refrain)
>   v. re·frained, re·frain·ing, re·frains
>   v.intr.
>   To hold oneself back; forbear: refrained from swearing.
>   **v.tr. Archaic**
>   To restrain or hold back; curb.